# Overclocking the AMD Phenom II X4 940BE

Tags: performance, cpu, overclocking

I'm not sure if this is the best site to post this sort of question if it isn't then I do apologize, other than that I hope I get relatively quick and good response :)

Firstly, I have already overclocked it to 3.62GHz (the 2 is some integer my BIOS adds for some reason) and it's stable done all the tests, 10 minutes for a rough idea and overnight test and passed with flying colors! All good and dandy with that, but my question is what is my limit on pushing this baby like I heard somewhere a few people have accomplished 3.8GHz and got a stable rig, so the real question is do I just up the multiplier to achieve the clock then the voltage? Or is there any other settings I need to tinker with?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might try superuser.com, but this is probably better suited for a hardware forum like http://www.overclockers.com/

Answer (score 0):

Raising the Multiplier and then the voltage would be the way to go. Just remember to do it in small steps.

The other thing that you may want to look at is the northbridge frequency. If your motherboard allows you may want to raise its multiplier a bit, it surprisingly seems to help stability.

Also, the phenom II chips like the cold more then most chips, so make sure to keep it as cool as possible.